# Using spread() to convert datetime into column name

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a data set that has two columns: the first is named 'key' and contains datetime (though currently in the form of a character), and the second contains more datetime values. I'd like to use spread to make the key rows become column names. Kind of complicated but once that is done I will convert the tibble to a list and use it with another function to create schedules that are named by the datetime column heading.

The data looks like this now:

```
new_dat <- structure(list(key = c("2018-01-01 01:00:00", "2018-01-01 01:00:00", 
                       "2018-01-01 01:00:00", "2018-01-01 01:00:00", "2018-01-01 01:00:00", 
                       "2018-01-02 01:00:00", "2018-01-02 01:00:00", "2018-01-02 01:00:00", 
                       "2018-01-02 01:00:00", "2018-01-02 01:00:00", "2018-01-03 01:00:00", 
                       "2018-01-03 01:00:00", "2018-01-03 01:00:00", "2018-01-03 01:00:00", 
                       "2018-01-03 01:00:00"), value = structure(c(1514835600, 1514920800, 
                                                                   1515013380, 1515100860, 1515173100, 1514925060, 1514994060, 1515088920, 
                                                                   1515181020, 1515271740, 1515011880, 1515079200, 1515174240, 1515256980, 
                                                                   1515345600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Boise")), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                     "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), .Names = c("key", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                               "value"))
```

And I want it to look something like this:

```
A tibble: 7,201 x 3
    `2018-01-01 01:00:00` `2018-01-02 01:00:00` `2018-01-03 01:00:00`
    <dttm>                <dttm>                <dttm>               
    2018-01-01 01:00:00   2018-01-02 01:00:00   2018-01-03 01:00:00
```

I used spread() and got the following error:

```
Error in eval_tidy(enquo(var), var_env) : object '' not found
```

Is it possible to make a datetime a column name with spread()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need a sequence column as there are duplicate records

```
library(tidyverse)
new_dat %>%
  group_by(key) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(key, value) %>%
  select(-rn)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  `2018-01-01 01:00:00` `2018-01-02 01:00:00` `2018-01-03 01:00:00`
#  <dttm>                <dttm>                <dttm>               
#1 2018-01-01 12:40:00   2018-01-02 13:31:00   2018-01-03 13:38:00  
#2 2018-01-02 12:20:00   2018-01-03 08:41:00   2018-01-04 08:20:00  
#3 2018-01-03 14:03:00   2018-01-04 11:02:00   2018-01-05 10:44:00  
#4 2018-01-04 14:21:00   2018-01-05 12:37:00   2018-01-06 09:43:00  
#5 2018-01-05 10:25:00   2018-01-06 13:49:00   2018-01-07 10:20:00
```